# Java jersey REST project not giving response

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am developing REST API. I am using Jersey framework. I set up my project correctly. But when I hit URLs to the browser, no response is coming from server. Also nothing is logged in the server console. No warning no error.

**My project hierarchy is**

[image]

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.sun.rest</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>readme.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.sun.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**Status.java**

```
package com.sun.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/v1/status/*")
public class Status {

    private static final String api_version = "00.01.00"; //version of the api

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnTitle() {
        return "<p>Java Web Service</p>";
    }

    @Path("/version")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String returnVersion() {
        return "<p>Version:</p>" + api_version;
    }
}
```

**Response**

[image]

Comment: why do you need "*" in path of your Status class? Remove that.

Comment: @almasshaikh thanks bro . Now it is working :) But do you know why my question down voted

Comment: @almasshaikh can you please tell me in web.xml what should be the value of <param-value> of servlet init parameter ??

Comment: AFAIK You don't need anything. Also i am not sure who downvoted and why. Anyways i am going to say the same in answer so it would be helpful in future to users with similar issues.

Comment: @almasshaikh thanks :) can you please give a +ve vote .??

Answer (score 1):

You don't need /*/ in your path. If you remove that from your path, that would resolve your issue.